# Web api 2 oauth2 expiration sliding

Tags: angularjs, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2

i am building a SPA using Angular JS and web API2, use Oauth2 for authentication. My issue, token'expiration is fixed, such as 20 minutes. So how can we redirect to logion page if user does not have any request in 20 minutes?

Refresh token does not work because system will auto refresh token although user does not have any action in valid time.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use an `AuthorizeAttribute` and override `OnAuthorization`

```
public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
     string token = string.Empty;
     AuthenticationTicket ticket;
     //retrieve the token the client sent in the request...
     token = (actionContext.Request.Headers.Any(x => x.Key == "Authorization")) ? actionContext.Request.Headers.Where(x => x.Key == "Authorization").FirstOrDefault().Value.SingleOrDefault().Replace("Bearer ", "") : "";

     //Your OAuth Startup class may be called differently...
     ticket = Startup.OAuthBearerOptions.AccessTokenFormat.Unprotect(token);

     //verification using the ticket's properties. When it was set to expire (ExpiresUtc) or whatever other properties you may have appended to it's dictionnary.

    //if verification fails..
    //actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Verification failed.");
    //return;

    //Otherwise, send a new token with an extended expiration date...
     AuthenticationProperties refreshTokenProperties = new AuthenticationProperties(ticket.Properties.Dictionary)
     {
            IssuedUtc = ticket.Properties.IssuedUtc,
            ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(20)
     };

     AuthenticationTicket newToken = new AuthenticationTicket(ticket.Identity, refreshTokenProperties);
     string newTokenHash = Startup.OAuthBearerOptions.AccessTokenFormat.Protect(newToken);

     //add the new token to request properties. Can't add it to the header here, because creating response/response headers here will prevent process from proceeding to called controller method.
     actionContext.Request.Properties.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("Token", newTokenHash));
}
```

Then chain it with an `ActionFilterAttribute` filter:

```
public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
{
    if (actionExecutedContext.Response == null)
        return;

    var objectContent = actionExecutedContext.Response.Content as ObjectContent;
    //the token we put in the filter above...
    string tokenHash = (actionExecutedContext.Request.Properties.Any(x => x.Key == "Token")) ? (string)actionExecutedContext.Request.Properties.Where(x => x.Key == "Token").FirstOrDefault().Value : "";
}
```

You can either append a new header to the response, put in the JSON payload response or add it as a response cookie. Then you make your client use this new hash when requesting any other resource, that way the expiration will slide an extra 20 mins everytime.

You can register these filter attributes globally in `App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs`

```
config.Filters.Add(new ClassExtendingAuthorizeAttribute());
config.Filters.Add(new ClassExtendingActionFilterAttribute());
```

But as mentioned by jumuro, you could have your client simply use the refresh token. Depends if you want to your back-end or front-end to do most of the leg work.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Please accept the answer if that works for you, or if you have too low of a reputation to accept it, upvote it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to control timeout in client app.
When the client do a request to the resource server, the resource server validates the access token and if it's expired returns a 401 - Unauthorized response.
When the client gets the 401 from the resource server, needs to obtain a new access token from the authorization server, either using the resource owner credentials or the refresh token.
This is the behaviour specified by the [OAuth 2.0 protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749).
Please let me know if you need a deeper explanation.

Comment: So if the client is trying to get information from a controller's method (ie: /order/get/100) and gets a 401 response, it needs to be designed as to call the `/refresh` endpoint to get a a refreshed token? That's ok, but the request to /order/get/100 needs to be "replayed" again with the new token in the request headers. A sliding expiration prevents that.

Comment: Actually the client can be designed to call the /token endpoint with refresh_token grant_type, but this is optional in the protocol.

Comment: And yes, the client needs to repeat the request that obtained 401 response. Your proposed solution seems to work, but if the client do not have activity in more than 20 minutes, the user will have to enter their credentials again, besides it is a customization of OAuth 2.0 protocol. Using refresh token, the refreshing and repetition of the request is transparent to the user, therefore the user experience is better and you are following the protocol.